# Webstorm debugger breakpoints doesn't work in nodejs

Tags: node.js, debugging, breakpoints, webstorm

When I try to set a breakpoint and debug the file, the debugger just run the app without stopping at breakpoints.
This is my code:

```
console.log('123');
```

And this is my output:

```
/usr/bin/node --debug-brk=39765 --nolazy index.js
debugger listening on port 39765
123

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Does anyone has an idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Did you ever uncover the issue?  Bumbling through Webstorm setup now, and baffled by the same thing.

Comment: Downgrading nodejs from v7 back to v6 fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 17):

Try to disable **js.debugger.v8.use.any.breakpoint** in WebStorm registry.

You can do it by going to **Help** -> **Find Action**

In there just enter **Registry**.

For me disabling this option made debugging anything node-related *much* faster and much more predictable.

Comment: For me it worked on IntelliJ 2016.3. I came across this issue after upgrading from IntelliJ 14.

Comment: Worked for me at idea 15.0.6

Comment: I did this with webstorm 2017.1.3 not only did it not work, the option has now disapeared so that I cannot check it back.

Comment: @decapo you can click "restore defaults." the same happened to me and I was able to recover.

Answer (score 6):

Wanted to chime in and say that it is *absolutely critical* that you use `--debug-brk` and not `--debug` with getting WebStorm breakpoints to work for remote debugging as well as running the server directly from webstorm.

Even though `--debug-brk` technically just stops and waits for the debugger to join, and `--debug` allows you to join later, my breakpoints failed with just `--debug` no matter the remote configuration I tried.

As far as I can tell, connecting WebStorm 11 to a node.js server on the debug port, with only `--debug`, will connect but fail to load any breakpoints that work.

Comment: It adds `--debug-brk` automatically, as you can see in the question

Comment: My comment was to clarify the case for remote debugging.  Edited for clarification.

Comment: `--debug-brk` is now `--inspect-brk`

Answer (score 4):

disabling `js.debugger.use.node.options` in the webstorm registry helped me

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-47774#focus=Comments-27-4436526.0-0

Comment: Worked for me on WebStorm 2023.1.4 using deno plug-in.

Answer (score 3):

For me the issue was that WebStorm didn't play well with my typescripts. It would say debugger listening and then run through the entire program without stopping at the breakpoint as described in the question.

The workaround I used was to simply put the breakpoint in compiled js file and debug from there instead.

Answer (score 2):

Debug breakpoints not work in my PhpStorm 2016.3.2 with NodeJS 7.7.x. My expectation is, that WebStorm will have same issue.

If you **downgrade to Node 6** (I tested with 6.9.4), it starts working correctly.

Comment: Inserting a `debugger;` line in the js source seems to allow the breakpoints to trigger properly. (Node 7.7.3, PhpStorm 2016.3.2)

Comment: @RobertK.Bell Any idea why this works.. This seems like crazy hack. But I'm glad I found this!

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to `Run -> View Breakpoints...` or hit
   <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> in OS X.
2. Select your breakpoint from the list and make sure `Suspend` is checked.

[image: Enable Suspend]

Comment: I've checked this, and "suspend" checkbox is already checked: https://i.imgur.com/FBtCdYS.png

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue by enabling generation of 'map' file in the TypeScript configuration.
Add '--sourceMap' in Tools-->Languages & Frameworks-->TypeScript-->Options

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue in version 2022.2 but I don't think it is a problem with the version

Here are the potential solutions;

---

Go to;

> WebStorm -> Preference -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger

Click "`Allow unsigned requests`" checkbox and make it checked

This solved my issue.

---

Or

Check your local environment. What I mean by saying check your local environment is usually more than one service is trying to use the same debugger port if we speak about the e.g. nodejs.

You will get the following message if you try to run two services at the same time in the debug mode;

> Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:9229 failed: address already in use

Try to start the main service first that you try to debug.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that will help somebody, But I was facing the same problems in my configuration. I have Node.js application written in TypeScript (the API server).
My mistake was to start the application using my start script:

[image: start]

I was trying to use debugger build in WebStorm and default configuration:

[image: start configuration]

The mistake was that debugger couldn't connect to that kind of process. So I changed the configuration to run my second script that builds all sources first and uses node.js to run the index.js, take a look.

The script from package.json:

[image: start:local]

And the configuration:

[image: start:local configuration]

Now debugging works like a charm!

[image: Working Node.js debugger]

Answer (score 0):

I had an **auto-executed function** that was imported by my React component (`<View/>`), and that component was imported by the test, making it fail to stop on breakpoints on all test cases regardless or their content.

```js
// culprit
export const shaderRowLimit = (() => {
  const report = isCI() ? {MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_VECTORS: 1024, MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384} : get_webGL_report();

  return getPyramidRowLimit(
      report.MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE * report.MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE,
      -15,
  )
})();
```

The error shown in the test was unrelated, as it looked like a css selector not finding his target, the real error seems to have been `Error creating WebGL context.` coming from `get_webGL_report` function. It is supposed to be mocked... but maybe it is executed before Jest is able to intercept it.

I coded this stuff like a year ago, breakpoints might have been working before, or not.

All of this made it quite hard to debug. To find the issue: Make a most simple test file (with only one test case inside), check if it work with breakpoints in your projects, start gradually adding more stuff from the test that doesn't stop on breakpoints. Or work the other way, gradually removing stuff.

I also update my IDE to latest version just in case.

Edit: there seems to be another issue, importing `<App/>`, that contains `<View/>` in the same file seems to make breakpoint being skipped.