# WebStorm debug breakpoints not working for Node.js project

Tags: node.js, react-native, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to set up debugging breakpoints in a Node project which is a React Native front end application.

I am using WebStorm v2020.3 and Node v15.14.0

My settings for the Node.js run configuration of the project:
[image: My settings for the Node.js run configuration of the project are here.]

I have set breakpoints across the project and none of them get triggered.

My settings for the debug "Attach to Node.js/Chrome" run configuration:
[image: My settings for the debug "Attach to Node.js/Chrome" run configuration are here]

First, I run the project and get this output:

```
/usr/local/bin/node --inspect-brk /Users/lachlangrant/Git/RN-BILLI-APP/node_modules/react-native/cli.js start
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/051a5d86-ad54-4a6c-bbaa-366bbe8a938e
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

Next, I run the debugger and get this output:

```
Debugger attached.
                                                          
               ######                ######               
             ###     ####        ####     ###             
            ##          ###    ###          ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##           ##    ##           ##            
            ##         ###      ###         ##            
             ##  ########################  ##             
          ######    ###            ###    ######          
      ###     ##    ##              ##    ##     ###      
   ###         ## ###      ####      ### ##         ###   
  ##           ####      ########      ####           ##  
 ##             ###     ##########     ###             ## 
  ##           ####      ########      ####           ##  
   ###         ## ###      ####      ### ##         ###   
      ###     ##    ##              ##    ##     ###      
          ######    ###            ###    ######          
             ##  ########################  ##             
            ##         ###      ###         ##            
            ##           ##    ##           ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##          ###    ###          ##            
             ###     ####        ####     ###             
               ######                ######               
                                                          
(node:33264) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'splice' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
                 Welcome to React Native!
                Learn once, write anywhere



To reload the app press "r"
To open developer menu press "d"
```

Then I trigger the breakpoint using an emulator in Xcode, and nothing happens.

I have looked at a variety of threads including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30584923/webstorm-debugger-breakpoints-doesnt-work-in-nodejs?rq=1).

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what are you trying to debug - `react-native/cli.js` script or your React Native application? In the latter case, please use [React Native](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.1/react-native.html#ws_react_native_create_run_config) run configuration. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.1/react-native.html#ws_react_native_debug

Comment: I'm trying to debug my React Native application, but at the moment the instructions have been to run `react-native/cli.js` - that is what actually gets the app to run on my machine.

I've also used `npx react-native run-ios` or `npx react-native run-android` as well.

I'm not sure exactly which file the main project is, there is an `index.js` and a `node.js` in the root directory. Apologies if things are unclear (this is a project I am inheriting from someone and documentation is basically non-existent).

Comment: Following the above instructions worked, thanks.